# JQuery clone products field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a products page set up where a user can fill out fields to customise products (size, quantity, colour, etc). I also have a button where they can add another product and the same fields as before will appear below. However, I'd like to have a button where they can duplicate what they have just entered into the fields, so instead of adding a new set of fields, it copies what they have just entered.

https://jsfiddle.net/y0y7r3za/12/ this is the very basics of the code (cant post the real code for certain reasons).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#duplicate').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#product").clone().appendTo("#newArea");
    });
});
```

(example of code to allow the jsfiddle link).
The clone works and duplicates, however once I press the update button to 'save' the changes, and go back into the order to edit it, the cloned form is not longer there.

Any ideas as to why the clone disappears would be a great help!

Comment: Side note, if you are going to want to repeat products, you will want to change that from an id `#product` to a class `.product` as ids should not be repeated.

Comment: As far as why the `action_page.php` is not showing all the forms you previously created dynamically, we have no idea why without you sharing that php logic.  But that php logic would have to do that, if you are doing a form submit.  Otherwise your frontend would have to have a way to preserve that data between form submits and restore them on the next page load.  Or change the logic to submit with ajax and then your page doesn't reload and you do not have to restore anything.

Comment: `.newArea` != `#newArea` etc etc... You're confusing classes with IDs. Also, where is `rightDiv` in your code?

Comment: Fixed theb Fiddle, apparently I posted a different fiddle than I was supposed too.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function cloningElement(el){
   var source = el.closest(".clone-source").clone();
      source.removeClass('clone-source hide').addClass('cloned');
      source.appendTo("#newArea");
  }
  
  
  $(document).on('click', 'button[id="duplicate"]', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
   cloningElement($(this));
  });
  
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="clone-source" id="product">
<form action="/action_page.php">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Product information:</legend>
    Name:<br>
    <input type="text" name="name">
    <br>
   Size :<br>
    <input type="text" name="size">
    <br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </fieldset>
</form>
 <button type="button" id="duplicate">Duplicate</button> 
</div>
<div id="newArea">
 </div>
```